# How do we use Galois theory to show that an integral has no closed form?

Tags: calculus, galois-theory

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can you prove that a function has no closed form integral?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral)

How do we use Galois theory to show that an integral has no closed form ?
I know this is called differential galois theory. Perhaps a simple example such as the integral of $\dfrac{exp(x)}{x}$ ?